# Unrecognized Connections to SQL Server - Compromised?

Tags: networking, security, sql-server

I am noticing some unrecognized traffic coming to and from my SQL Server.

As you can see below, the domain in the image seems to be accessing SQL via multiple ports.  How can I learn more about this mysterious connection?

I have tried querying `exec sp_who` but none of the host names seem to match the one in question.

I also came across [this post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1786564-unknown-pc-names-showing-up-in-network-activity?page=1) whereby the author has a similar quandary; however, the answer seemed to be stale DNS info.

When I `ping` the domain, I see that it points to an AWS load balancer, but I don't think it's anything belonging to me.  How can I investigate this connection?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turn off name resolution so you can see the actual IP address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is there a way to do that safely without interrupting other services?